# How to use a function in another class and modify it Django

Tags: django, django-views

Sup, need to use a function in a different class without losing the model, while still being able to change the function(not important, I can rewrite func into more flexible func). Can't solve this issue at least 10 hours. Google didnt help =( I know code is a little dirty, I will clean that :D

Don't worry

I have same header with form and another form in all pages.

Need form from class head in class stockpage. And everyone template and future classes as well.

Views

```
class head(View):
    template_name = "dental/mainpage.html"
    model = signup
    def get(self,request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = UserSign
            return render(request, "dental/mainpage.html", {"form": form})
    def FormSign(self,request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserSign
            if form.is_valid():
                body = {
                    'Name': form.cleaned_data['Name'],
                    'email': form.cleaned_data['email'],
                    'Number': form.cleaned_data['Number'],
                }
                info_user = "\n".join(body.values())
                send_mail(
                    'Sign',
                    info_user,
                    'eric1122221@mail.ru',
                    ['eric1122221@mail.ru'],
                    fail_silently=False) 
                return render(request, "dental/mainpage.html", {"form": form})   #self.template_name
            return render(request, "dental/mainpage.html", {"form": form})                     

class stockpage(ListView):
    template_name = "dental/stocks.html"
    model = stock
    context_object_name = "stocks"
```

HTML

signuphtml

```
{% load static %}
{%block css_files %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "signup.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<section id="forms">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="txt" class="form-control {% if form.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
                 {{ form.label_tag }}
                 {{ form }}
                 {{ form.errors }}
            </div>
    <div id="buttsig">
        <button id="b4" type="submit">записаться</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

mainpage.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{%block css_files %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "header.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mainpage.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "signup.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
{% include "dental/includes/header.html" %}
    <div ="d1">
        <ul>
            <li>blabla</li>
            <li>blabla</li>
            <li>blabla</li>
            <li>blabla</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{% include "dental/includes/signup.html" %}
{% include "dental/includes/tail.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

stocks html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{%block css_files %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "header.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mainpage.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "signup.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "stocks.css" %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
{% include "dental/includes/header.html" %}

<section id="contentstock">
    {% for stock in stocks %}
     <li>
        <h4>{{ stock.title }}</h4>
        <img src="{{ stock.image.url }}" alt="{{ stock.image }}"/>
        <h4>{{ stock.content|linebreaks}}</p>
     </li>
    {% endfor %}
</section>

{% include "dental/includes/signup.html" %}
{% include "dental/includes/tail.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What function? In what class? Code is VERY dirty ._.

Comment: @Som-1 code rewritten a million times. I know how to write correctly:D 

need form from class head in class stockpage. And everyone template and future classes as well.

Comment: You should just use a FormView, and you can use an `{% include %}`d fragment for the form on each page (or inherit it as a block from a super-template).

Comment: @AKX
let me add templates

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding separate view for handling the form with hidden field for url to redirect to. Django's default [auth views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) work like this. Also custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) may help to provide the form for all pages without overriding all their `get` or `get_context_data` methods.

Consider the example:

forms.py:

```python
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    next_url = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
    name = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

context_processors.py:

```python
def my_form_context_processor(request):
    my_form = MyForm()
    my_form.fields['next_url'].initial = request.get_full_path()
    return {'my_form': my_form}
```

settings.py:

```python
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'my_app.context_processors.my_form_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py:

```python
class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = 'my_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # ...
        next_url = form.cleaned_data.get('next_url')
        if not next_url:
            next_url = reverse('my_app:home')  # default
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)


class ViewA(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template_a.html'


class ViewB(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template_b.html'
```

template_a.html:

```html
{% include "my_form.html" %}

<h1>A</h1>
```

template_b.html:

```html
{% include "my_form.html" %}

<h1>B</h1>
```

my_form.html:

```html
<form action="{% url 'my_app:my_form' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Go!"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: swears at "next" in context_processors.py and at url 'api:my_form' but there I don't know what I need to put. Help sansei! =)

Comment: what does it say for 'next'? As for 'api:my_form' you should reverse your url of the form view. E.g. in my urls it's like follows: `path('my-form-view/', MyFormView.as_view(), name='my_form'),` and the app name is `api`, then i reverse it as `api:my_form`.

Comment: also, `next` is a keyword in python. In case your editor swears on it, you may rename it to something like `next_url` or `redirect_to`, etc.

Comment: thx greatfully. I need to go, but I guess i will do that eventually.

Comment: I did it! That costs me a lot of nerves, but I closed this problem. Thank you. Found some sections where I need an urgent lessons =)